# How can one express that a relationship must not be cyclic?

Tags: alloy

Consider a `upgrades` relationship:

[image: Incomplete order relationship]

I need to make sure that `upgrades` cannot be circular. How can I do that in Alloy?

Comment: To fellow readers, there is a question as to which site this belongs on. Feel free to offer advice on that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to enforce transitivity and antireflexivity.

```
fact {
  no a: Item | a in a.upgrades
}

fact{
  all a,b,c: Item |
  a in b.upgrades and b in c.upgrades implies
  a in c.upgrades
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest *pointfree* syntax? Your first fact may be written as `no upgrades & iden`, and your second fact may be written as `upgrades.upgrades in upgrades`.

Answer (score 2):

From your example, I infer that the `upgrades` relation is not intended to be transitive:  in the example, a diamond sword upgrades a stone sword, and a stone sword upgrades a wooden sword, but the pair WoodSword -> DiamondSword is not in the `upgrades` relation.

So what you want to say is something like

```
fact upgrades_acyclic {
  no x : univ | x in x.^upgrades
}
```

Some modelers prefer the more succinct formulation in terms of relations:

```
fact upgrades_acyclic { no ^upgrades & iden }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Since almost two years have passed since I asked this question I can't remember what I actually was working with, whether or not I really didn't want transitivity. So I don't know if this is a problem with my question or my answer D: